# How to receive commands from Socket in Actionscript 3?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, sockets, actionscript, serversocket

I finally managed to get a server working (after 2 days playing with java lol) so i can connect with it using sockets.
But what bothers me is, let's say I connected both clients to the server using these sockets
How can i send commands, for example attack from one client to the other?

I hope you get my point lol :/
PS:I'm using java for the server, as3 for the client

Thanks in advance anyway...

Comment: Basically I believe you need to look into communicating between threads in Java to pass the data from one thread to the other.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816005/communication-between-threads-in-java-stopping-a-thread-if-another-thread-has-f You'll need to update all clients when data is sent to the server (aside from the client that is broadcasting) to get some multi-player action going.  I believe usually UDP is used instead of TCP for it's speed, despite the lack of reliability for fast paced, multi-player games.

Comment: Well i use Actionscript 3, not java :/

Comment: It sounds like in your question you use AS3 client side and Java server side.  The client (AS3) needs to send data to the server (Java), then the server (Java) needs to pass that data to the other client (AS3).  If you're doing some sort of P2P client side thing it's not clear in your question.  Essentially you need to have Java act as a "bridge" for the data to go from one client to the other, otherwise there's no way for them to communicate.  Just so you know the Socket classes aren't supported on mobile that I know of, so you'd have to roll your own ANE if you want mobile.

Comment: No, the game i'm trying to create isn't mobile related

Comment: Yeah so what I was saying initially is on the server side (Java) you'll have two threads running (for two clients), one to handle each client socket connection, then you need to just be able to communicate between those threads.  If you need more help you'll have to show the code you're trying to make work, the part that does the AS3 socket connection to Java and the Java side of the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Java side is a RedDwarf Server, AS3 socket connection is just a simple .as that tells if i can connect to the RedDwarf server, but if i use this .as in my game, it won't do anything (just tells if i'm connected), i want this socket, to recieve and send commands to the game, and yea the game is played by 2 people, but i will use a server to connect all pc's so people can play private games or with a random guy...

Comment: You'll have to read up some more on the details of using the server I think if you run into specific issues post back here with some code to get more help: http://electricdreamsofsheep.blogspot.com/2010/09/multiplayer-online-gaming-actionscript.html Best of luck.

Comment: I think u didn't get my point lol...That's where i was based creatin the Java server. I just want a way to learn how can i use sockets to send commands to the other client

Comment: I've seen a chat program that uses BlazeDS on Adobe web site. I think [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add either BlazeDS (a little outdated) or GraniteDS (newer and in my opinion works better), I do think BlazeDS was a little easier to get going with.

They are both based on using a java webservlet and actionscripts AMF format to allow communication with a flash/actionscript client.

The other option is to use some form of C/C++/C# to actually talk binary.  This is extremely efficient if you want to create your own protocol.  On the other hand this means more work :).